# To prove isomorphism $(I^{-1}J/J)/q(I^{-1}J/J) \cong I^{-1}J/(J＋qI^{-1}J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Let $K$ be a number field and $R_K$ be ring of integers of $K$.
Let $I,J⊂R_K$ be ideal of $R_K$. Let $q$ be an ideal which divides $I$.

I want to prove $(I^{-1}J/J)/q(I^{-1}J/J) \cong I^{-1}J/(J＋qI^{-1}J)$.

My text's hint says 'we use $R_KJ=J$,this is a point' but I think we never use $R_KJ=J$ to prove titled isomorphism.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What is "an ideal which decides $I$"?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. 'divides' is correct.